# How to give a list of sections that will be included as part of the form in Liferay7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am migrating from liferay 6.2 to liferay 7 ,here I am getting problem to give the selected list of categories in the form.

Ex:
In the site settings by default we can able to see four different categories and its sub-categories in the form.

which are defined in the **portal.properties** in the following way

```
sites.form.update.main=details,categorization,site-url,site-template
sites.form.update.seo=sitemap,robots
sites.form.update.advanced=default-user-associations,staging,analytics,content-sharing,recycle-bin
sites.form.update.miscellaneous=custom-fields,display-settings
```

**1)Basic Information**

*a)details,    b)categorization,    c)site-url,    d)site-template*

**2)Search Engine Optimization**

*a)sitemap,   b)robots*

**3)Advanced**

*a)default-user-associations,   b)staging,analytics,   c)content-sharing,   d)recycle-bin*

**4)Miscellaneous**

*a)custom-fields,   b)display-settings*

**We can include only some specified  selected categories based on the role.**

In liferay 6.2 we can avhive this  by defining in the 
**portal-ext.properties** like the below

```
#These custom properties are defined for portal admin

    sites.form.update.main.admin=details,categorization,site-url,site-template
    sites.form.update.seo.admin=sitemap,robots
    sites.form.update.advanced.admin=default-user-associations,staging,analytics,content-sharing,recycle-bin
    sites.form.update.miscellaneous.admin=custom-fields,display-settings

#These custom properties are defined for portal site admin  

     sites.form.update.main.siteadmin=details,site-url
     sites.form.update.seo.siteadmin=
     sites.form.update.advanced.siteadmin=recycle-bin
     sites.form.update.miscellaneous.siteadmin=
```

**But How could I achieve the same functionality in Liferay7 ?**

Comment: Maybe this article helps: [configuring-form-navigator-forms](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/configuring-form-navigator-forms)
I have not tested it, but it looks that those settings are used to modify visible sections.